# WPF keybinding gesture with HOME/END not working

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a WPF app and I am trying to associate a custom key gesture to a command. i tried these:

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="HOME" Command="customCommand"/>
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl + HOME" Command="customCommand"/>
<KeyBinding Gesture="ctrl + Alt + HOME" Command="customCommand"/>
```

none of them will work. but I then tried

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl + H" Command="customCommand"/>
```

it worked as expected.

I'm wondering what's the difference between `Ctrl+H` and `Ctrl+Home`? Is there anything internally in WPF that's blocking the HOME/End key from triggering commands?

UPDATE:
I think I found why it's not working. basically we defined a key binding on the very top frame level. the structure is like this: 
Frame 
   Tab Control 
     User Control

Inside the user control, user pressed HOME button trying to trigger the top level command. but seems the tab control intercepted and handled the command. In this case, the HOME button is really doing focusing on the first tab item. 
is there a way to bypass the tab control so the top level Frame can directly handle it?

Comment: post the relevant XAML. Which UI element are you applying these `KeyGestures` to?

Comment: if you found the answer to this, please post an answer or delete your question. Don't leave it open forever.

Comment: I encountered the exact same issue, using Home did not work but Ctl+H did... upvoting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabControl` handles the Home key in the `OnKeyDown` method, this then moves focus to the first tab item.

The only way to circumvent this behavior is to create your own control derived from `TabControl` and override the `OnKeyDown` method. For example:

```
public void MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key != Key.Home)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This will then stop the default `TabControl` handling of Home key.

Comment: My Home command is defined within Window.InputBindings of my MainWindow and I have the same problem.